# How to dynamically select a resultMap based on the value of a column in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

I have a resultSet from DB, that returns say two records as below

```
TRANID Type Name Amount
1      B    ABC  100.00
1      S    XYZ  -100.00
```

The above data represents a transaction where a seller and buyer are involved.

Now I need to map the above resultset to MyBatis, such that it returns me a transaction object in below structure.

```
Transaction :{
    id : 1,
    buyer:{
       name : "ABC",
       Amt : "100.00"
    },
    seller: {
       name: "XYZ",
       Amt: "-100.00"
    }
}
```

If the DB had returned the data in one row, with both buyer and seller data in one dimension like

```
TRANID BNAME BAMOUNT SNAME SAMOUNT
1      ABC   100.00  XYZ   -100.00
```

then I can use a resultmap something like below

```
<resultMap id="transactionRM" type="Transaction">
 <id property="id" column="TRANID"/>
 <association property="buyer" type="User">
   <result property="name" column="BNAME"/>
   <result propert="amt" column="BAMT"/>
 </association>
 <association property="seller" type="User">
   <result property="name" column="SNAME"/>
   <result propert="amt" column="SAMT"/>
 </association>
</resultMap>
```

I will be able to achieve what I wanted, because I have unique aliases/column names for buyer and seller.

But how can I achieve the same results, if the results come in two row, where one is a buyer and seller, and type is a discriminator that determines if the row belongs to seller or buyer.

I tried to define a resultMap for User, like

```
<resultMap id ="buyerRM" type ="User">
   <result property="name" column="Name"/>
   <result property="amt" column="Amount"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id ="sellerRM" type ="User">
   <result property="name" column="Name"/>
   <result property="amt" column="Amount"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="transacionRM" type="Transaction">
  <association property="buyer" resultMap="buyerRM" type="User"/>
  <association property="seller" resultMap="sellerRM" type="User">
</resultMap>
```

The above resultmap will not work, as same column names defined for both buyer and seller and the data will be duplicated.

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a problem to change the query so that it joins the result to itself by transaction id so you get one row with both buyer's and seller's data?

Comment: That is another option I'm thiking about. But was trying to handle the case without modifing the SQL

Answer (score 1):

**Associations** only work for single rows. The closest thing you can get to what you want is by using **collections**.

```
<resultMap id="transactionRM" type="Transaction">
 <id property="id" column="TRANID"/>
 <collection property="users" type="User">
   <result property="type" column="Type"/>
   <result property="name" column="Name"/>
   <result property="amt" column="Amount"/>
 </collection>
</resultMap>
```

This will return a **single** object with a property `id` and a property `users`. The latter is a `List<User>`, that in this particular case will have **two elements** (one for each row). Not exactly what you want but close.

You'll need to transform that `List<User>` into two separate properties.

Comment: It is possible to map associations returned in different rows. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to map this in mybatis 3.4.6 without query modification.

If you do modify query you have several options.

### Self-join

The original query can be transformed to do a self join by transaction id column. This way you will a row per transaction and can map it as you described in your question.

### Columns renaming

It is possible to map associations that span multiple rows. Object data may span multiple rows. Mybatis maps rows data to objects using `id` mapping element, that is rows that have the same `id` value belong to the same object so data from them is used to fill constructed object (whether it is a subordinated item belonging to collection or an association).

If you can wrap original query or modify it directly to set values into different columns based on type you can do that.

By wrapping I mean something like:

```
select
    TRANID,
    case Type when 'S' then Name else null end as seller_name,
    case Type when 'S' then Amount else null end as seller_amount,
    case Type when 'B' then Name else null end as buyer_name,
    case type when 'B' then Amount else null end as buyer_amount
from (
   -- original query goes here
)
```

And map it like this:

```
<resultMap id ="userRM" type ="User">
   <result property="name" column="name"/>
   <result property="amount" column="amount"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="Transaction" id="twoRowMap">
    <id column="TRANID" property="id"/>
    <association property="buyer" resultMap="userRM" columnPrefix="BUYER_"/>
    <association property="seller" resultMap="userRM" columnPrefix="SELLER_"/>
</resultMap>
```

Note that due to a bug in mybatis you need to specify `columnPrefix` in capital letters in mapping.

This would select one `Transaction` object with correctly set `buyer` and `seller` properties.

Comment: Good solution -- though requires a small query modification.